# wordpress plugin editing php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm editing a plugin very poorly, I have very little experience in it, but I have made some adjustments based on trial and error.

I have a foor each loop and I'd like t wrap the whole thing in a `div` with a class of `projects`

```
    foreach ($this->catlist->get_categories_posts() as $single) :
        $this->lcp_output .= $this->lcp_build_post($single);
        $this->lcp_output .= $this->get_category_link('div class="column-2"');
        $this->lcp_output .= $this->get_date($single);
        $this->lcp_output .= $this->get_thumbnail($single);
    endforeach;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What plugin is it, what theme are you using, and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/ and I'm trying to wrap each post output in a div.

Comment: Looks like Steven's answer was the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->lcp_output .= '<div class="projects">';

foreach ($this->catlist->get_categories_posts() as $single) :
    $this->lcp_output .= $this->lcp_build_post($single);
    $this->lcp_output .= $this->get_category_link('div class="column-2"');
    $this->lcp_output .= $this->get_date($single);
    $this->lcp_output .= $this->get_thumbnail($single);
endforeach;

$this->lcp_output .= '</div>';
```

Comment: Thats great, I moved it within the foreach loop and now they are individual projects. Thanks heaps @steven